# Angular 1.x calling function from controller

Tags: angularjs

Avery basic problem.

In my Angual 1.x app I have a function which I call from my template:

```
searchesDTController as results
results.filterResults = function(filter = null) {}
```

However I also want to call the same function within my controller:

```
vm.filterResults();
```

This give me:

```
ReferenceError: vm.filterResults is not defined
```

I also tried:

```
filterResults();
this.filterResults();
```

Why does angular report the function as not defined when it clearly is?

Here is my code:

```
function searchesDTController(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

var vm = this;
vm.dtInstance = {};
vm.search = search;
vm.oneAtATime = false; // for the collpase/expand accordion
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
    .fromSource('/listings/filter.json?string=' + vm.search)
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withDOM('frtip')  
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('bServerSide', true)
    .withOption('sDom', 'lBfrtip')
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
    .withDisplayLength(10);
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Listings.id').withTitle('#').withOption('name', 'Listings.id').renderWith(function(data, type, res) {return res.id;}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false)
        .renderWith(function(data) {
            return '<a href="/listings/view/'+data.id+'"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">View</button></a>';
        }),   
];

vm.dtColumns[0].visible = false; // hide the id column - not needed

vm.filterResults("a-string"); //line 28

vm.filterResults = function(filter = null) { /* code */ }
```

The error occurs at line 28

**Plunkr with fix**

https://plnkr.co/edit/YXhEBDDbFzG05Bwe844w?p=preview

Comment: Please create a quick [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com and post the link in your question. That should clarify why you are getting the error to anyone reading your question.

Comment: @igor please see the pastebin added to my question

Comment: Don't post a link. That's against the rules here. Post the relevant code in the question itself. With 116 questions posted and 1K rep points, you should know that a question about code requires the code.

Comment: Hey @AlanA : can u please create a plunkr.com demo ? It would give u super quick solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line

```
vm.filterResults("a-string");
```

`vm` doesn't containt `filterResults` because it is not set. You should change code order, assign function first, then call it

```
vm.filterResults = function(filter = null) { /* code */}

vm.filterResults("a-string");
```

Comment: wow it was actually starring me right in the face. I have included a plunkr in my question.